# prove or disproof problem about linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

prove or disprove:

if $V$ is a vector space and $T:V\to V$
is a linear transformation so that $\mathbf T^2= 0$
(the zero transformation)

then $\operatorname{Im}(T)\subseteq\ker(T)$

have no clue...

Comment: Hint: start with definitions of $\ker T$ and $Im\,T$

Comment: ker(T) $\implies$v$\in$  V so that T(v) = 0

Answer (score 1):

To show $\operatorname{Im}(T)\subseteq \ker(T$), start with an element $v\in\operatorname{Im}(T)$ and try to show that $v\in\ker(T)$. The definition of $\operatorname{Im}(T)$ says that there exists $w\in V$ such that $v=Tw$. According to the definition of kernel, you want to show that $ T v=0$. Substitute and use the given property of $T$.

Comment: And after going through this, maybe tell me how it is possible to *avoid* finding this ...